# Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical

Tags: google-search-console, php

I use https for my website. all my http requests are redirected to the https. I have submitted my sitemap. and google search console is showing below error for few of my web pages.

```
Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical
```

my few essential pages is not showing up in google search results because of above error.

how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifcally submiting these links to the search engine to index them within your sitemap.
The searchengine has already indexed them with other URLs.

e.g.
Already indexed
http://myhomepage.com/contact.html  
SEO URL
http://myhomepage.com/Contact/

Now these links link to the same content. Therefore the SEO URL is a duplicate so you have to specify that in your sitemap.

Canonical is the tag you give the prefered link for duplicate content. so in this example you would add the canonical tag so the search engine knows that this content of the duplicate URLS is your prefered one.
You can also redirect 301 or set a noindex for the "wrong" urls you dont want to be indexed.

[Here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) is the google description and how to resolve it

Comment: I have added rel='canonical' with url in my preferred page. will google resolve it automatically? or is there a way to inform google about the correction i made

Comment: if you just did it, you can log into the google searchconsole and resubmit your sitemap. If you see some index errors beeing resolved by tomorrow or the day after you just wait otherwise you did something wrong.

Comment: It has past more than 24 hours. I don't see any index errors resolved. what could be the reason?